# Return only one object in an array of objects

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "9278456798091",
    "description": "schools in the us",
    "schools": [
      {"name": "washington", "age": 90},
      {"name": "howard", "age": 80}
    ]
}
```

I want to query the schools array such that it only returns the particular object that matches the query. This is what I am doing

```
filter := bson.M {"schools": bson.M{"$elemMatch": bson.M{"name": "howard"}}}
```

This returns the entire document. How can I return something like this at least -

```
    {
    "id": "9278456798091",
    "description": "schools in the us",
    "schools": [
    {"name": "howard", "age": 80}
    ]}
```

Or this

```
    {
    "schools": [
    {"name": "howard", "age": 80}
    ]}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's your problem using `$elemMatch`?. The query should works, check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d-MnuB4gxqC)

Comment: @J.F. It returns the entire document. Here is the query - `filter := bson.M {"schools": bson.M{"$elemMatch": bson.M{"name": "howard"}}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `aggregation` framework, `$project` pipeline and `$filter` operator, like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "schools": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$schools",
          "as": "school",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$school.name",
              "howard"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/yysDXoN5vNl

Answer (score 0):

You can use *projection* to show the first matching element from the array field `schools`. E.g.,

```
var result bson.M
opts := options.FindOne().SetProjection(bson.M{"schools.$": 1, "_id": 0 })
filter := bson.D{{ "schools.name", "howard" }}
err := collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), filter, opts).Decode(&result)
```

Returns:

```
map[schools:[map[age:80 name:howard]]]
```

You can include or exclude other fields from the result using the *projection*, for example:

```
opts := options.FindOne().SetProjection(bson.M{"schools.$": 1, "id": 1 })
```